# Sci-Fi novel where Earth is taken over by a race called the Cateni(?)

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

Does anyone know the name of a novel (part of a series, I think) about Earth being taken over by a race of aliens called the Cateni or Cat-*something*.

Some human people and a renegade from the alien race are exiled on another planet.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it?

Answer (score 17):

Anne McCaffrey's "[Freedom Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catteni_Series)" of books feature a race called the ***Catenni*** who have enslaved humanity.

Freedom's Landing (published 1995)
Freedom's Choice (1996)
Freedom's Challenge (1998)
Freedom's Ransom (2002)

> In Freedom's Landing, the **Catteni** routinely round up human
>   troublemakers and **drop them on empty planets** – if they survive, the
>   world is suitable for their own people. Kristin is included in such a
>   group, which is dropped on a world they name Botany (after the
>   Australian destination for transportees, Botany Bay). **Surprisingly, a
>   Catteni noble, Zainal, is among their group** - the same one Kristin
>   helped earlier. While trying to cope with their new situation, they
>   discover the existence of another alien race that is using the planet
>   as a gigantic farm. Kristin is at first the only one to vouch for
>   Zaniel but he soon proves his usefulness to the rest of the improvised
>   colony.

[image]

Comment: That's the one! Thanks Richard.

Comment: @Marie - If this answer has been helpful, don't forget to upvote and mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

Eric Brown's *Kethani*

From the [Amazon blurb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/184416473X):

> It takes an alien race to show us what humanitiy *[sic]* truly is. This is the irony faced by a group of friends whose lives are changed forever when the mysterious alien race known as the Kethani come to Earth bearing a dubious but amazing gift: immortality. These superbly crafted episodes deal with human emotions in the face of the vast consequences of the alien arrival, and show how people across the world react to this benign invasion, how ultimately we evolve as we gain the stars.