# What is the title/author of this obscure SciFi book where aliens sell coffee?

Tags: story-identification, novel

For awhile now I've been trying to remember the title of a book I read when I was about 13 (around 2010). The book was definitely in the Science Fiction genre and was likely the second or third book in an ongoing series but I randomly chose it instead of the first book. It was in english and by the cover art and wear of the book I could tell it was at least 10 yrs old.

So all I remember is that It details the struggle of a colony of a human-like race that previously escaped either imprisonment or persecution (likely in the first book of the series) and relocates to new planet. They had some interesting ways of sustaining their new colony like selling coffee (yes, coffee) at other space stations/planets. I recall that this was successful for them.

The story focused primarily on like a handful of characters that were leaders in their colony. There was a sort of 'love' triangle between three of them where one woman had either one or two children with one or both men. She liked her kids but had them mostly in order to sustain the colony's population growth. It just wasn't a thing that either man was jealous of the other's child with the woman since they knew it was their duty to help the colony grow. One of the men was definitely more alien than the other, therefore his child was half alien. The  children were cared for at a facility that cared for multiple children while their parents where off building the new colony.

The leaders in this love triangle were a part of a larger crew who sold coffee off-planet in order to bring in revenue. How they got the coffee I can't remember, but it was a delicacy to their customers.

Thanks for any information about the title/author! I just really want to read the series and finally figure out why those aliens needed to sell so much coffee!

Comment: `when I was about 13` is not very descriptive, to say the least. You could also add the language in which you read it and, maybe, country and medium (e.g. anthology, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate (confirmed by OP comment): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56447/51379

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it may be possible that you are thinking of the 'Freedom' series by Anne McCaffrey. There are three books in the series. Coffee is used as a trade item in the second and third books.

The books main character is a woman called Kristin Bjornsen. She is in a relationship with an alien who is similar to but non human called Zainal. 
She has two children with two different human fathers - their Colony world has a low population and the children are encouraged for genetic purposes.

Comment: Yes It is! Thank you so much!!!